# Multiple domain names with a single Facebook App ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read on this Quora thread that it was possible for a single Facebook App ID to work across multiple domain names, but that it was something you had to request from the Facebook dev team. Could someone verify this? I wasn't sure where to place a request.

http://www.quora.com/Facebook-Connect/Why-doesnt-Facebook-accept-an-IP-address-as-a-valid-base-domain-for-Facebook-Connect